# Single-press TemplateBox deletion

Tags: front-end, notebooks, syntax, editing, boxes

One of the handy things about `TemplateBox` is that it can be used to define an alias for a more "natural symbol" (by having an empty list first argument and setting the appearance in a `DisplayFunction` option). The only drawback to this usage, as far as I can tell, is that when trying to delete the "Symbol" the whole `TemplateBox` is highlighted  forcing a second *delete*.

So, for example, for some reason my muscle memory has never really taken to `@*` (or `\*`) so I'd like to re-define this as per:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"fc" -> TemplateBox[{},"Composition", DisplayFunction -> ("\[EmptySmallCircle]" &),
     Editable -> False,
     Selectable -> False,
     InterpretationFunction -> ("@*" &),
     SyntaxForm -> "@*"]}]
```

but with the cursor placed viz:

[image]

on pressing *Delete* the selection moves to the `TemplateBox` viz:

[image]

Curiously, a left arrow from that cursor position skips the whole `TemplateBox` so I might expect a *delete* to equally treat `TemplateBox` as a whole unit which also seems to be a normal expectation for a "Symbol" with no template slots. Is there an option/workaround to ensure that a `TemplateBox` "Symbol" is deleted with a single *delete*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently there is no way to achieve the deletion of the TemplateBox via a single delete. Normally the TemplateBox has arguments so the promotion of the selection to the whole of the TemplateBox generally makes sense, however in the no argument case I can see the appeal of just deleting the entire TemplateBox. I'll discuss this with colleagues and maybe implement this in the next cycle. Thanks Ronald!

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Jason, there are several examples of other applications of the no-argument case scattered here which might support a justification. Oh and welcome to SE! There is apparently some code-of-conduct boilerplate to communicate but I'll just point to the one about developers implementing all user-requests :)